# How to change url after success in ajax without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the ajax

```js
$(".urut").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>categories/brand/<?= $link_brand; ?>?l=<?= $l; ?>&h=<?= $h; ?>&city=<?= $city; ?>&city_name=<?= $city_name; ?>&ket=view",
    type: "POST",
    data: "urut=" + $(".urut").val(),
    success: function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
    }
  })
})
```

This works, but i want the url to change because I have many parameters there and of course with the `data: "urut="+$(".urut").val(),` parameter as well.

Comment: if you change url it wil reload. sorry if i misunderstood your question. if i did please clarify

Comment: Why would you reload a page because of needing to add more parameters to an `ajax` request? I'm not sure I understand. (Side note, did you know you can pass an object with key-value pairs?)

Comment: `history.pushState(). history.replaceState()`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do this to your success action :

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

See this post to [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511) for a basic how-to.

> Additional Note:
>
> 1. The first parameter is the data we'll need if the state of the web
>      page changes, for instance whenever someone presses the back or
>      forwards button in their browser. Note that in Firefox this data is
>      limited to 640k characters.
> 2. title is the second parameter which can be a string, but at the time
>      of writing, every browser simply ignores it.
> 3. This final parameter is the URL we want to appear in the address
>      bar.

It's now available in most "modern" browsers.

Comment: Too bad I beat you by about a minute to it :)

Comment: it's almost finish, but i don't know how the rule to add parameters in  "object or string". can you show to me? :) @sherlyfebrianti

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea i've been editing the answer because the comment box cannot support any enter. :)

Comment: i've found it, btw thanks a lot, your answer really help me @sherlyfebrianti

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea okayy, just upvote my answer and mark it as an answer if it really help you :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the browser history to change the url bar in JS.

```
      history.pushState()
     history.replaceState()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
 $(".urut").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>categories/brand/<?= $link_brand; ?>?l=<?= $l; ?>&h=<?= $h; ?>&city=<?= $city; ?>&city_name=<?= $city_name; ?>&ket=view",
        type: "POST",
        data: "urut=" + $(".urut").val(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            window.history.pushState("Details", "Title", "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/yourNewPage");
        }
    });
});
```